# A non-negative definate matrix has a non-negative generalized inverse

Tags: regression, self-study, generalized-linear-model, statistical-learning, matrix-inverse

I'm having trouble proving a N.N.D matrix has a N.N.D G-Inverse.

So far I have:

If we assume x = Az where x >= 0 and A is a nnd matrix.  So if Y is a G-inverse than:

x = Az = YAz = Yx >= 0 .

Thus

Lx = LAz = Az >= 0 .  So L is any G-inverse of A is also nnd.

Comment: Is this for a class? Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) to understand how we deal with such questions.

Comment: @gung It's more for a paper I'm trying to under about non-negative matrix factorization and generalized inverse for machine learning.  http://bit.ly/1qtKiMT

Comment: Hint: SVD. ${ }$

Comment: Please give more information. Define exactly what you mean by non-negative definite because as it reads it does not mean what you think it means. You are talking within the context of non-negative matrix factorization and you are referring to the values of the matrix. "Non-negative definite matrix" refers to positive semi-definiteness within the context of $z^TAz \geq 0$. Clearly for any PSD (or NND) matrix the inverse is also at least the same but this is not what you want...

Comment: It's exactly what the question says, a non-negative definite matrix.  But thanks to @cardinal , I got the answer from his himt.